# Inserting a date into a table using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PDO insert statement that is not inserting the information and I am at a loss as to why.  Here is my statement:

```
   $log = $conn->prepare("insert into log_activity (user, event, date) values(:who, :event, :date)");
   $log->bindParam(":who", $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $log->bindParam(":event", $event, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $log->bindParam(":date", $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $log->execute();
```

I use a similar one (just no date) for registration that works perfectly.  Here is the values:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $event = $_POST['thing'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
```

I know there are values there, and I am not throwing an error statement.  I have tried removing the date thinking that it might be the issue and it still does not work.  I am sure I am just missing something easy, but can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jim is `$name` really of type `INT`?

You can leave it up to PDO to determine the type you know, you don't have to be explicit

```
$log = $conn->prepare("insert into log_activity (user, event, date) values(:who, :event, :date)");
$log->bindParam(":who", $name);
$log->bindParam(":event", $event);
$log->bindParam(":date", $date);
$log->execute();
```

Or just dont bind:

```
$log = $conn->prepare("insert into log_activity (user, event, date) values(:who, :event, :date)");
$log->execute(array(':who'=>$name, ':event' => $event, ':date'=> $date));
```

---

Make sure your connection is set to throw errors:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Yes, name is either a 1 or 2 depending on who the user is (it comes from a select statement)

Comment: Added the error attributes, turned out the database table was changed and I had the wrong field names.  Update them and it works fine now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `,` in the first line after `:event`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: thanks, but that still did not solve the issue.  I still have nothing inserting into my table

Comment: There is also problem with `,` again in the first line after `date`.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue either,  I have posted the updated query.